# How can i do CORS POST request on Laravel 5 and AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

i am use

> github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

with default configuration

and i was success with GET request,

when i do POST request,

on console network tab, that POST status is 200,

BUT i got an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/data. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to define the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header on your laravel application.

To allow ANY domain to request resources from your laravel application:

```
$response = Response::make($contents, $statusCode);
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the:
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
setting in the Apache configuration or htaccess file.
Then check if your changes are correct:
`apachectl -t`
and restart your webserver `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I originally voted this down due to formatting but I figure it's probably better to give you some feedback. Check out [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to format your answer so that it might be readable and understandable by someone who may not know exactly what "the Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * setting" is